# Is "always" omitted in mathematics?

Tags: terminology, natural-language

Consider the statement: "For two numbers a,b their product is positive". For this statement to be true it must be true for every a,b right? So is the above statement equivalent to: "For two numbers a,b their product is ALWAYS positive"? Why "always" is omitted?

Comment: It is implicit in the [universal quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) : "for every a, b..."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the statement "For two numbers..etc" would be better to be replaced by "for every a,b...etc" ?

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: Not to poke fun, but is "always" omitted from your question?  I think some turns of phrase seem more or less natural given certain voices, and some variations on similar statements may communicate the essential content to the same degree.

Comment: Yes, it is a common convention that unquantified variables in statements are [impicitly universally quantified](http://faculty.up.edu/wootton/Discrete/Section2.1.pdf), when no confusion arises (and it can when one truly does intend free variables). It is a conversational shortcut for [universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation), where a universally quantified variable is replaced by a constant (standing for a generic individual) in natural deduction proofs.